# Routing the message with List Generic payloads using payload-type-router in spring-integration

Tags: java, spring-integration, payload, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to use the payload-type-router in xml based config of a legacy app and the application neither route to the specific channel nor throw any error at that instance. can we route the message of type List<?> using payload-type-router using XML configuration. I have n't found much examples in the doc as it only mentions routing using Integer, String classes but not with List.

```
 <int:payload-type-router input-channel="run-router-channel">
        <int:mapping type="com.foo.req.BlRunnerRequest" channel="runner-channel"/>
        <int:mapping type="java.util.List" channel="run-channel"/>  <!-- can spring integration support this approach-->
 </int:payload-type-router>
```

Thanks in advance. What could be the alternatives for this kind of routing in XML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We can. I have just modified the unit test in the project to this:

```
<payload-type-router id="router" input-channel="routingChannel">
    <mapping type="java.lang.String" channel="channel1" />
    <mapping type="java.lang.Integer" channel="channel2" />
    <mapping type="java.lang.Number[]" channel="channel3" />
    <mapping type="java.lang.Long[]" channel="channel4" />
    <mapping type="java.util.List" channel="channel5" />
</payload-type-router>
```

The I do this in the test method:

```
testService.foo(new GenericMessage<>(new ArrayList()));
PollableChannel channel5 = (PollableChannel) context.getBean("channel5");
assertThat(channel5.receive(100).getPayload()).isInstanceOf(List.class);
```

Probably something else is going on in your case and that request payload is really not a `java.util.List`.

Also router has this logic when it cannot deliver the message to some channel:

```
    if (!sent) {
        getDefaultOutputChannel();
        if (this.defaultOutputChannel != null) {
            this.messagingTemplate.send(this.defaultOutputChannel, message);
        }
        else {
            throw new MessageDeliveryException(message, "No channel resolved by router '" + this
                    + "' and no 'defaultOutputChannel' defined.");
        }
    }
```

Since I don't see a `defaultOutputChannel` configuration from your code snippet, that only means a `MessageDeliveryException` is thrown. If you don't see it in your case, then you swallow it somehow.

Comment: yes, you are right, Thanks for the answer. issue was there's a service-activator in between which accepts the message and returns void (nothing) so the message was lost in the process. Is there any beginners intro to spring integration module..the documentation seems very very lengthy. : )

Comment: Well, the most typical is Cafe Demo: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/applications/cafe. You can find there many more other sample. But again: it is hard to have a simple tutorial since every one's use-case is different.  You may need to start from the theory to understand deeper what is messaging and how those EIP fit in such a solution: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/